# Is it possible to have babel-polyfill issue a warning/error instead of generating boiler plate code?

Tags: babeljs, eslint, babel-polyfill

This might be more of an eslint question

I have to support IE7, and ideally I would use eslint (or something other inspection tool) to detect object "methods" not compatible with IE7 and other legacy browsers (for example, `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Object.entries`).

The primary compatibility plugin (that I can find) for eslint can't do it and doesn't seem to optimistic about it either: https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat/issues/72#issuecomment-288834016

The same author began another plugin to solve this issue, but it is marked as WIP/do not use and hasn't been updated in quite some time: https://github.com/amilajack/compat-db

The only thing I've found that seems to detect these methods is babel's polyfill, but it is important this library is as small as possible, so I would prefer to just see a warning when a developer uses something not available

Is there some way to accomplish this, or have I missed something about eslint?